# Many-To-Many relationship with same Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `User` entity which can be a `Manager` or `Client`, `Manager` can have many `Clients` and `Client` can have many `Managers`.

I tried to map the `User` entity like this:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  private UUID uuid;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "managers_clients",
      joinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "clientUuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "managerUuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false)})
  private List<UserEntity> managers;


  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "managers")
  private List<UserEntity> clients;
```

But unfortunately, I have an error:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.company.domain.common.entities.UserEntity.managers, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Can someone explain why this happening and how can I overcome this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to fetch a lazy-loaded collection after the session was closed. [This article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-initialize-proxy-exception) has more information. A quick fix would be to fetch the collection eagerly (`@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`), but this would affect all queries on this entity since all `manager`s are always fetched. A proper way would be to access the collectoin at a point in time where the session is still open (i.e. in a `@Transactional` method).

Comment: @Turing85 how to implement a `@Transactional` method?

Comment: `@Transactional` is a CDI annotation. You just annotate a method with it. The rest is done through JPA and the CDI container (the CDI container will produce a proxy object that wraps the actual implementation and adds code to begin and commit transactions on transactional methods). I would recommend the [JavaEE tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/cdi-basic.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have a session during the fetching of the data.
I'm not sure where you are fetching data, but try to add @Transactional to this method.

This will make sure the JPA uses a session to get the data.